# Zend Framework 2 - How do I change the view script in the controller plugin?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a problem with Zend Framework 2.

I want to have 2 view scripts for each action to display the appropriate view for PC and smartphone. I know how to change the layout:

```
$viewModel->setTemplate(layout_path)
```

but I could not find out how to change the view script.

I have following files in the index view folder, `Application/view/application/index`, for `IndexController`:

```
index.php  (view file for PC)

index_sp.php  (view file for smartphone)
```

How do I change the view script to `index_sp.php` in the controller or controller plugin?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do here..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to change the actual layout view file you can do this inside your controller:

```
// example to change base layout for ajax requests
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $this->layout('layout/ajax-layout');
}
```

If you want to change the view used by the current view model / action you can do this inside your controller/action:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
    'form'      => $form
    'something' => $something
));
$viewModel->setTemplate('mymodule/newview.phtml');

return $viewModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function doSomethingCrazyAction()    {
    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'message' => 'Hello world',
    ));

    // This is the way to change render(view)..
    $view->setTemplate('modulename/controllername/phtml-file-name');

    return $view;
}
```

Docu: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html